# Sobreposição de informações ao utilizar Media Queries

Tags: html, css

Desenvolvi esse site [www.prolinesound.com.br](http://www.prolinesound.com.br), na versão para desktop tudo está perfeito porém quando comecei a ajustar as media-queries pra deixá-lo mais amigável para dispositivos móveis, encontrei um problema. Quando clico no link *"quem somos"*, ele obstrui parte do texto, e se clico em algum outro link (que esteja funcionando) e depois clico em "*quem somos*" ele posiciona a tela acima de onde deveria.

Alguém pode me ajudar??

HTML

CSS responsivo

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px){
.pageTopo{
    width: 520px;
}
.pageWhite{
    padding: 50px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 520px;
}
.pageGray{
    padding: 50px 0px 10px 0px;
    width: 520px;
    min-height: 750px;
}
.container{
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

CSS padrão

```
.pageTopo{
background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
```

}
.pageWhite{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 70px 0px 25px 0px;
}
.pageGray{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 70px 0px 25px 0px;
}
.container{
    width: 1020px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

Comment: obstruir em que sentido, mais detalhes!

Comment: poderia colocar o CSS utilizado para a responsividade do problema em questão?

Comment: Por favor mande o código para que possamos ver o que pode estar errado.

Comment: Ao acessar o site em testar a responsividade em muitas resoluções a perda de informações, recomendaria a você que tentasse utilizar bootstrap ou medias queries padronizadas para um resultado ainda melhor, é algo simples e que com certeza agregará mais valor ao site.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a ferramenta do google Chrome para testar seus layouts para versões de dispositivos móveis, com este recurso você poderá identificar o css que está sendo utilizado em determinada parte do site e corrigi-lo prontamente.

Comment: Eu utilizo no caso a extensão Pendule do google chorme que é muito boa para teste de design responsivo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, nos meus sites eu utilizo float: left; juntamente com width: 100%; nas classes css de todas as divs, impedindo assim de ocorrer essa questão de sobreposição de divs na tela;